# Using Python to control system audio i [Voice Control]

Tags: python-3.x, audio, voice-control

I'm writing a program to control my system volume either increase or decrease in voice command. but I don't know how and what are all the packages should to be installed? I'm using python 3.7.0 in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but u can probably use tkinter. I had created a duplication GUI file so just copy this code and paste in python:

```
from tkinter import  *

try:
    root=Tk()
    root.title("file copier")

    fname=mystring=StringVar()

    root.geometry = Canvas(root, width = 3000, height = 3000)
    label=Label(root,text="enter the file name with file extension", fg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)
    entry=Entry(root, textvariable=fname) .grid(row=0, column=1)


#specifying the function going to be assigned to the button
    def duplicatefunction():
        print(fname.get())
        with open(fname.get(),"rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
        with open("copy file(rename this file and copy info inside).exe","wb") as f:
            f.write(data)

    
    button1=Button(text="duplicate file", command=duplicatefunction) .grid(row=0, column=2)

    root.mainloop()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("no such file found named", entry)
```

so if u see i have typed exe extension after file name in the function. Try typing all ur code in a notepad and then convert to exe from this file(after pasting the code save the file and run it), u can do that from changing extension but u should make copy too, anyway this file's code was only for ur reference and btw the copy file will be in pycharm only, if u use it for python IDLE like me it will come in file explorer. convert a notepad file from this by duplicating the file and then go back, type ur code for the volume and use this code at the end for the code to control volume:

```
fname=StringVar()
print(fname.get())
        with open(fname.get(),"rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
```

so the data should be read and work, i hope it does cuz it works for me, in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting on https://techoverflow.net/2020/04/04/how-to-set-windows-audio-volume-using-python/
but this only works for Windows.

The package they are using is `pycaw`. You can install it with
`pip install pycaw`.

That is the script on the website:

```py
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
import math
# Get default audio device using PyCAW
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
# Get current volume 
currentVolumeDb = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(currentVolumeDb - 6.0, None)
# NOTE: -6.0 dB = half volume !
```

If I use

```py
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-65.25, None)
```

my system volume is set to 0

and with

```py
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(0, None)
```

I can set the system volume to 100